# selenium click works as a hover over

Tags: selenium, python-3.x

I want to search through a table, looking for a key string "admin" in column 1; if found, click on a "login" button from the same row. "login" button is always on column 9.

the python code I am using is:
`new = master.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(td[1], 'admin')]/td[9]")`

My code successfully found the row that has "admin" string, but when I tried to execute

```
new.click()
```

selenium performed a "hover over" action instead, e.g. it did not click on the button, but I saw this button's https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/otr/index?do=login_customer&id=xxxxxx&user_id=xxxxxxxxxx displayed at the bottom left corner of the webpage.

Can anyone help?

Sample Html code for the table I am searching in is:

```
<table class="table1" id="main_table" style="width: 850px;"> 
<tbody>
<tr class="us_dark">
<td>admin</td>
<td> <a target="_blank" href="?do=login_customer&id=xxxxxxxxx&user_id=xxxxxxxxx">Login</a>
</td>
```

Today I tried using Chrome instead of Firefox, it worked. I suspected that this issue might be caused by incompatibility between Firefox 31 and Selenium 2.42

Comment: Provide please sample of html. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I tried using Chrome instead of Firefox, it worked. I suspected that this issue might be caused by incompatibility between Firefox 31 and Selenium 2.42